# Need to upgrade subchart inside Helm Chart

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have one helm chart inside that I have couple of subchart and install the master chart .Both the application is running fine. But I want to know if I made some changes in one of the application code and want to upgrade that subchart only.How I can do it ? If I am running helm upgrade chart/subchart then it start only subchart which I am passing other one(pod) is getting deleted.

So how can I upgrade only one subchart without touching other subcharts(application)

main chart name -- test
sub chart name -- frontend and backend

I have upgraded the subchart with command helm upgrade  test/frontend but it only upgraded the fronded one the backend pod get deleted automatically.

I want that only my frontend pod get redeployed without touching the backend one.

Comment: You can't do this; Helm will always send Kubernetes manifests for the entire combined parent chart to the cluster.  Though, if a Deployment's contents are unchanged, Kubernetes won't do anything with the running Deployment, and deleting and recreating a Pod is usually harmless.  Consider separately installing the two charts (maybe using a wrapper tool like Helmfile) if you need to manage their lifecycles separately.